# React Native ListView - rowHasChanged doesn't fire

Tags: react-native

I am trying to implement an infinite scroll in React Native. Below is the source of the component:

```
var React = require('react-native');
var server = require('../server');
var Post = require('./Post');
var SwipeRefreshLayoutAndroid = require('./SwipeRefreshLayout');
var backEvent = null;
var lastPostId = "";
var isLoadingMore = false;
var isLoadingTop = false;
var onEndReachedActive = false;

var {
    StyleSheet,
    ListView,
    View,
    Text,
    Image,
    ProgressBarAndroid,
    BackAndroid
} = React;

class Stream extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.ds = new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => {
            console.log("rowHasChenged FIRED!!");
            return false;
        }
    });

    this.state = {
        dataSource: this.ds.cloneWithRows(['loader']),
        hasStream: false,
        posts: []
    };

}

componentDidMount() {

    BackAndroid.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => {
        this.props.navigator.jumpBack();
        return true;
    }.bind(this));

    server.getStream('', '', 15).then((res) => {

        lastPostId = res[res.length-1].m._id;

        this.setState({
            posts: res,
            hasStream: true,
            dataSource: this.ds.cloneWithRows(res)
        }, () => onEndReachedActive = true);
    })
}

onRefresh() {
    var posts = this.state.posts;
    var firstPost = posts[0].m._id;

    console.log(this.state.dataSource._rowHasChanged);

    isLoadingTop = true;

    server.getStream('', firstPost, 4000)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(posts.length);
             posts = res.concat(posts);
             console.log(posts.length);
             this.setState({
                dataSource: this.ds.cloneWithRows(posts),
                posts
             }, () => {
                this.swipeRefreshLayout && this.swipeRefreshLayout.finishRefresh();
                isLoadingTop = false;
             });
        }).catch((err) => {
            isLoadingTop = false;
        })

}

onEndReached(event) {

    if(!onEndReachedActive) return;

    if(this.state.loadingMore || this.state.isLoadingTop)return;
    isLoadingMore = true;
    var posts = this.state.posts;
    server.getStream(posts[posts.length-1].m._id, '', 15)
        .then(res => {
            console.log('received posts');
            posts = posts.concat(res);
            lastPostId = posts[posts.length-1].m._id;
            this.setState({
                dataSource: this.ds.cloneWithRows(posts),
                posts
            }, ()=>isLoadingMore = false);
        })
}

renderHeader() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.header}>
            <Text style={styles.headerText}>Header</Text>
        </View> 
    )
}

renderRow(post) {

    if(post === 'loader') {
        return (
            <ProgressBarAndroid 
                styleAttr="Large" 
                style={styles.spinnerBottom}/>
        )
    }

    let hasLoader = post.m._id === lastPostId;

    let loader = hasLoader ? 
        <ProgressBarAndroid 
            styleAttr="Large" 
            style={styles.spinnerBottom}/> : null;

    return (
        <View>
            <Post 
                post={post}/>
            {loader}
        </View> 
    )
}

render() {


    return (
                <ListView
                    style={styles.mainContainer}
                    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                    renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}
                    onEndReached={this.onEndReached.bind(this)}
                    onEndReachedThreshold={1}
                    pageSize={15} />
    );
}
}
```

The problem is that whenever I append (or prepend) new data, the `rowHasChanged` method of the `DataSource` doesn't fire. It just re-renders every row, even tho nothing has changed (except the new data).
Any idea why the method is bypassed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Edit:** Pass a function to setState to avoid race conditions

I just figured it out. If you are having the same issue, check the point at which you change your state with the new `dataSource`. Mine was like this:

```
this.setState({
    dataSource: this.ds.cloneWithRows(posts)
});
```

Instead you should always use the `dataSource` from the previous state, like this:

```
this.setState(state => ({
    dataSource: state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(posts)
}))
```

Cheers!

Comment: Does anyone know if this is documented anywhere in the React Native docs? I can't find it mentioned specifically and this seems important...

Comment: If you're using the current state to update the state, you are supposed to use the form `this.setState((state) => ({dataSource: state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(posts)}));`. Passing setState a function reduces risk of a race condition.

Answer (score 4):

this worked for me, hope this helps. I created a new dataSource and assigned the updated data to it on state change as follows:`

```
var dataSource = new ListView.DataSource(
  {rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => ( r1 !== r2)});

  this.setState({ dataSource : dataSource.cloneWithRows(posts) });
```

Now, the new data is assigned and the view is rendered correctly. Note that posts array that is assigned now holds the updated data. Still wondering though if it's the best way to do it but it works!

Comment: This is not the answer. The code in original question, The new data is also get assigned as normal and view is render correctly, too. The question is why rowHasChanged not called when new data come. To reproduce it, you need to put a console.log in rowHasChanged and please put a console.log in the render(). And you will find that using this code all row, no matter old, new, changed not changed, will be re-rendered after the setState is called. The correct answer is answered by Rado himself below.

Answer (score 1):

I agree it ***seems*** to make sense that you should always use the dataSource from the previous state.

Yet when I setState this way, **rowHasChanged** gets called for all rows, however, **rowHasChanged** always returns **false** and no rows are rendered???  Why?

```
  // This is callback handler that the ListView DetailView will 
  // call when a ListView item is edited
  onChange(waypoint: Object){
    console.log('Callback: rowNumber= ', waypoint.rowNumber);
    console.log('        length(m)= ', waypoint.distance.meters);

    var itemListChanged = this.state.itemList;
    itemListChanged[waypoint.rowNumber-1] = waypoint;
    this.setState({
            dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(itemListChanged),
    });
  },
```

If I setState this way, **renderRow** is called for all rows unconditionally without **rowHasChanged** ever being called.  Which is correct?

```
this.setState({
  dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(itemListChanged),
});
```

ListView, datasource, and react-native are a hard learning curve coming from C#/C/C++.

Comment: May be you could post your constructor, rowHasChanged function.

Comment: One guess is you didn't make "passed by value", but "passed by reference", which means, this.state.dataSource is already changed to the same value ( as they point to the same ram address). Let say you assign an apple basket a, it render apple, you take out the apple and put an orange to basket a, you think it is comparing apple with orange, but actually, you are comparing the things in basket a with basket a. You are compare orange with orange.

Comment: The solution is you assign an apple to basket b first and then when you compare the things in the basket, put orange in basket c. you need to have more than 1 basket in order to compare. In short you put a props in a state, once the props changed, the state is already changed before you call setState.

Comment: @Ed of the Mountain  Facing exactly same issue. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

for anyone still having issue with **rowHasChanged** called but are still returning **false** the following snippets might help

the datasource is initialized like usual:

```
let ds = new ListView.DataSource ({

  rowHasChanged: (a, b) => {
    const changed = (a !== b)
    return changed
  }

})

this.data = []

this.state = {
  listDataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(this.data)
}
```

here is the function which will update a row

```
updateRow = (row, rowId, sectionId) => {

  // make a shallow clone from the stored data array
  let blob = this.data.concat()

  // modify the row, since we are using the triple equal operator, we need to make sure we are giving it a new object (new ref)
  blob[rowId] = Object.assign({}, blob[rowId], {label: blob[rowId].label + '..cape..deh'})

  // tell react to update the source
  this.setState({
    listDataSource: this.state.listDataSource.cloneWithRows(blob)
  }, () => {
    // we need to update our data storage here! after the state is changed
    this.data = blob
  })

}
```